# Eloquent Laravel - selectRaw() in whereHas()'s closure

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to select sum of points and pass it into where clause. Following is my code:

```
    $query->whereHas('evaluations', function ($q) use ($params)
    {
        $q->selectRaw('sum(evaluations.point) as points')
            ->where('points', '>=', $params->point);
    });
```

But it alerts `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'points' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a WHERE for columns created with SELECT. You have to use HAVING statement like `->having('points', '>=', $params->point)`

Comment: select d1.update_id from ( select update_id, count(update_id) as ct from updates_tags where tag_id in (67,33,86,55) group by update_id) as d1 where d1.ct=4

How to convert this into laravel query ?

Comment: The point is that you cannot have _aggregate_ columns in your WHERE clause, you must use HAVING. This is not a Laravel/Eloquent limitation. Use the `having()` method instead of `where()` as outlined in the answer and it will work.